# Spring Child Context Closes Parent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I have a Spring application that makes use of a child/parent context relationship.  The reason for the this is to ensure that the child context inherits beans/resources from the parent and then adds more beans/resources to override those as needed.  However, when the child context closes (exits try/catch scope) it begins to do cleanup on all the beans it has references to, including those in the parent scope.  This is undesirable, as I need to reuse that parent context to create another child context, but it is now garbage because it contains a bunch of disposed/shut-down beans.

Questions:

1. Is this the desired behavior of a child context in that it should cleanup the parent beans?  If so, why?
2. I would like for the child context to only clean up the beans it has directly defined, not the inherited beans.  Is this possible?

Here is some relevant code:

```
private AbstractApplicationContext createChildContext(Path workspacePath, String catalogPath, boolean force, Map<String, String> buildOptions) {
        // Set the properties to pass into the new context
        Properties props=new Properties();
        props.setProperty("workspacePath", workspacePath.toString());
        props.setProperty("databasePath", workspacePath.toString() + File.separator + "data");
        props.setProperty("catalog", catalogPath);
        props.setProperty("force",String.valueOf(force));
        PropertiesPropertySource pps=new PropertiesPropertySource("properties",props);

        // Create new context
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.setParent(applicationContext);
        context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(pps);
        context.scan(Neo4jConfig.class.getPackage().getName());
        context.register(Neo4jConfig.class);

        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beans = context.getBeanFactory();
        BuildConfigurationService buildConfiguration = (BuildConfigurationService)beans.createBean(BuildConfigurationService.class);
        buildConfiguration.setBuildConfiguration(buildOptions);
        beans.registerSingleton("buildConfiguration", buildConfiguration);

        context.refresh();

        return context;
    }
```

And in the Neo4jConfig we do this...

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableNeo4jRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableCaching(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@Import({ConversionServiceConfiguration.class})
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

...

        @Bean GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService(@Value(value = "${databasePath}") String databasePath) {
                logger.debug("Creating database using '{}' for the database path.",databasePath);
                GraphDatabaseService graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(databasePath);
    ...
```

Comment: That shouldn't be happening so you must be doing something strange/wrong in your code.

Comment: Like what?  Is there a switch to disable this?

Comment: No, as mentioned this shouldn't happen so you must be doing something strange. Without seeing code/configuraiton/setup that isn't to determine.

Comment: OK, I've written some simplified test cases which seem to confirm what you are saying.  However, I still have some issue with the child context closing parent beans....   The problem I have is coming from a @Configurable bean.  It isn't initializing and it is because the BeanConfigurerSupport class seems to be shut down by the child context closing, thus making my configurable beans unable to be configured.  Somehow, the child and parent contexts are using the same BeanConfigurerSupport class.

Comment: As mentioned post some code to see what you are doing differently as compared to your testcase.

Comment: I wish it were that simple.  The codebase is very large and I cannot reproduce the problem in a stripped down example.  Any ideas where to look would be helpful.  What I am seeing is that my parent context is sharing the same BeanConfigurerSupport class as my child context.  When the child closes, the BeanConfigurerSupport shuts down and cannot be used again even though the parent context is still using it.  Also, I am unsure why the parent and child contexts are sharing this object.  In a stripped down example, they do not show the same behavior.

Comment: You must have some beans that are leaking information/classes/instances between contexts. Or you have a holder for an `ApplicationContext` in a static variable that is receiving callbacks or some sorts. Without the codebase it is hard to tell.

Comment: To give you a bit of insight into the setup...  It is all Java config, annotated.  Using component scan on both the parent and child contexts, and using some @ConditionalOn* to filter out unwanted beans from the parent context.  Somehow the parent and child context end up with the same instance of the BeanConfigurerSupport class, but I am not sure why.  Any experts out there on the @Configurable annotation?  Any other ideas are appreciated, I will continue digging...

Comment: You say `@ConditionalOn*` which implies Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes, this is a spring boot application.  Auto-configuration is on.

Comment: In Spring Boot by default there is only a single context.

Comment: Yes, and then I manually create a child context...  `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
  context.setParent(applicationContext);
  context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(pps);
  context.scan(Neo4jConfig.class.getPackage().getName());
  context.register(Neo4jConfig.class);  context.refresh();`

Comment: You either `scan` or `register` both is overkill and can lead to bean duplication. You shouldn't need to add the property sources as those should be merged already (what is the `pps` bean and why are you adding it yourself?). Could you at least add the `Application` class containing this code to your post?

Comment: The pps is one of the reasons why we create a child context.  We are  using an embedded db and we need to configure the db location based on some calculated values from the parent context.

Comment: Actually, I'm not describing that correctly...  We pull values from the command line and then pass into a child context so the db can be configured based on command line args.  So the child context and pps is basically used as a way to configure from command line args.

Comment: For some reason looks like you are doing too complex things for configuring things but that is from my chair. I think the issue is in duplicated beans, holding static references. Which ones is hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is coming from the `@EnableSpringConfigured` annotation on the child context.  Vaguely described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-configurable-container).

When the child context closes, the static `BeanConfigurerSupport` bean gets closed and is no longer usable.  However, because it is static (also used by the parent context), any future `@Configurable` beans fail to get configured.

I'd love if someone could comment on whether this is a bug or desired behavior.